Ecto where not in array still just includes rows
I am attempting to create a system in a phoenix web app using ecto where I have a many-to-many relationship between table A and table B. Table C is used to create the join between these two.
problem
I need to perform a query where I take * from A where there isn't a relationship between A-B where B.name in exclude
My current code
The first where works just fine, but the second one fails, even though when I IO.inspect the query it is in there. I don't get why the second one wouldn't work if the first one does.
# include : [string]
# exclude : [string]

query
|> join(:inner, [a], ba in assoc(f, :bs))
|> join(:inner, [_, ba], b in assoc(ba, :as))
|> where([_, b], b.name in ^include)
|> where([_, b], b.name not in ^exclude)
|> group_by([f], f.id)


I don't fully understand the query - b.name in ^include and b.name not in ^exclude can be simplified to b.name in ^(include -- exclude). Is that what you want?

I wish for all a objects to be excluded who have a b object associated with them that has a name which appears in the exclude list. The reverse of that applies to the include list. In this case the include list works, however the second where is simply ingnored.

Please update the post with sample data, expected output data, and the generated query. I suspect that the problem is that the query is testing each row in ba to see if its associated b is included but not excluded. The query should instead find all a in ba where there exists an included b and there does not exists an excluded b. Try changing the code to use a subquery to identify all a that are associated with an excluded b and removing those from the a that had included b. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Ecto, so I can't provide actual code.

Also seeing your Ecto.Schema could be useful
